# Shortcut for Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

In my Sublime Text 3, the shortcut Ctrl+A moves cursor to the front of line as expected. However, Ctrl + E does not move cursor to the end of line. Then, I find out that this works: Command+RightArrowKey on Mac.

Anyone knows why Ctrl+E does not work as expected in the official shortcut documentation? What command shall I configure in the keybinding map?

My User key binding is very simple.

```
[
    { "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When keys don't do what you expect in ST3 it's a good idea to install [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts)

Install it through Package Manager and it'll help you work out why things aren't doing what you thought they should

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts listed are specific to the platform and the version of the Sublime Text. [Here](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html) is the list of all the shortcuts, there is also a comparison chart [here](http://www.wdtutorials.com/sublime-text/sublime-text-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet-win-os-x-and-linux#.VeYgC3UVhBc). Further, if you are getting started with Sublime Text3 this [link](https://blog.generalassemb.ly/sublime-text-3-tips-tricks-shortcuts/) might prove helpful.

Comment: Thanks. however, Ctrl + E described in the document for Mac OS X does not work on Mac OS X.

Comment: Probably because ⌃+ E is taken by some other program. Can you post the key bindings for your sublime text.